# Powershell for Automation of sending mails via a path

Tags: powershell, automation, email-attachments

I want to automate the process of sending mails via outlook by using Powershell in such a way that, if I have many files in a  particular folder provided by a path, it should fetch each file from that folder as an attachment to a mail.
**Means separate mails should be sent for each files in that path**

```
$OL = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application

Start-Sleep 5

<#
olAppointmentItem
olContactItem
olDistributionListItem
olJournalItem
olMailItem
olNoteItem
olPostItem
olTaskItem
#>

#Create Item
$mItem = $OL.CreateItem("olMailItem")

$mItem.To = "PlayingWithPowershell@gmail.com"
$mItem.Subject = "PowerMail"
$mItem.Body = "SENT FROM POWERSHELL"
$file = "C:\Users\Desktop\Xyz"
foreach($files in Get-ChildItem $file)
{
 $mItem.Attachments.Add($files)
 $mItem.Send()
}
```

*Tried like this but showing error like "Could not find member , cannot call a null valued expression, item has been moved or deleted"*

Please help me out.

Comment: If you want to send separate mails for each attachment, you should create a **new** mailitem with properties every time. However, why send it via Outlook?

Comment: Why Outlook? Just use `Send-MailMessage`

Comment: Probably you should `-filter` the Items of `Get-ChildItem` a little more and only inlude `-file`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, if you want to send a new email for each file found in the folder, you should create a **new mail item** inside the loop and send that.

Also, you use (IMO) confusing variable names..

- the path for the files you call `$file`
- the single file item used in the loop you call `$files`

so if you don't mind I have changed that below to have the variable names more meaningfull.

Also, `Get-ChildItem` can return both [DirectoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo) and [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) objects. Since you only want files, use the `-File` switch.

```
$path = "C:\Users\Desktop\Xyz"

$OL = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application

foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File)) {
    # create a new mail item object for each file to attach
    $mItem = $OL.CreateItem("olMailItem")

    $mItem.To      = "PlayingWithPowershell@gmail.com"
    $mItem.Subject = "PowerMail"
    $mItem.Body    = "SENT FROM POWERSHELL"
    # Outlook wants the full path and file name, not a FileInfo object
    $mItem.Attachments.Add($file.FullName)
    $mItem.Send()
}

$OL.Quit()
# clean-up used COM object
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($OL)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Thanks man. it helped me. I wasn't generating a new mail